# How do I make inApp PDF File Download?

Tags: java, android, download

I have an android app, and I want to make the PDF's inside it to be downloaded inside the APP only, only the signed in users would be able to view it. How can I make it in Android Studio (Java)

if anyone have the idea please share it

Answer (score 0):

android download File? look at this lib:

https://github.com/lingochamp/FileDownloader